# Javascript code causing stylesheets to disappear from site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/timer/viewer.php

Long story short, if I include the Countdown function inside getJSON, the stylesheets disappear from the code inspector in chrome, and the page does not display the external stylesheets or any inline styles.

What could cause an HTML page to completely lose all it's styles like this?

Comment: Page is actually losing both the <title> and <style> tags.

Comment: Your javascript produces an error, which may cause the problem.

Comment: What error? It's not giving me one.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in viewer.php:32, which is `next = new Date(data[i][0]);`

Comment: strange. I don't get that error at all, 

The line is 

next = new Date(data[i][0]); The counter shouldnt work at all if data[i] wasn't defined.

Comment: The counter doesn't work at all for me. I'm getting the same error

Comment: Hmm. That seems really hard to troubleshoot then. I'm using chrome, maybe the issue manifests in different ways in different browsers. Trying IE to see what happens

Comment: I'm also using chrome, so that's not the issue ;)

Comment: As long, as your script might break the whole page functionality, we can't reproduce your initial problem.

Comment: Ah, that was a time zone issue. I get the same error if there are no times in the future. Anyone west of Atlantic time would have had that error.